# Why aren't my soldiers getting promoted?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I have a character with 8 missions and 6 kills, and still she is a rookie. Some seem to get promoted, while others get sent on missions, make kills, and yet stay as rookies. Is this a bug, or is there something else controlling how soldiers get promoted? I am playing on Classic difficulty.

Comment: I notice that nobody has gotten promoted when I retreat from a mission. Could that be it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That sounds like a bug.  One kill is good for the first promotion.  I have never read anything that suggested soldier advancement was slower on Classic.

Comment: its definitely not slower on classic from what I've noticed, sounds like a bug to me

Comment: One point of *damage* is enough for a promotion. You just need to draw blood.